# Error on fitting RDD data on decision tree classifier

Tags: pyspark, rdd

```
#load dataset
df = spark.sql("select * from ws_var_dataset2")
def labelData(data):
    # label: row[end], features: row[0:end-1]
    return data.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row[-1], row[:-1]))
training_data, testing_data = labelData(df.rdd).randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], seed=12345)
```

I get error on running the following cell:

```
model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(training_data, numClasses=2, maxDepth=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={}, impurity='gini', maxBins=32)
```

**Error**: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.

Any idea on why this is erroring out?

Following is the Full error stack for reference:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-43c2f1c0de4c> in <module>
----> 1 model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(label_df, numClasses=2, maxDepth=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={}, impurity='gini', maxBins=32)

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/tree.py in trainClassifier(cls, data, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins, minInstancesPerNode, minInfoGain)
    214         """
    215         return cls._train(data, "classification", numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo,
--> 216                           impurity, maxDepth, maxBins, minInstancesPerNode, minInfoGain)
    217 
    218     @classmethod

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/tree.py in _train(cls, data, type, numClasses, features, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins, minInstancesPerNode, minInfoGain)
    138     def _train(cls, data, type, numClasses, features, impurity="gini", maxDepth=5, maxBins=32,
    139                minInstancesPerNode=1, minInfoGain=0.0):
--> 140         first = data.first()
    141         assert isinstance(first, LabeledPoint), "the data should be RDD of LabeledPoint"
    142         model = callMLlibFunc("trainDecisionTreeModel", data, type, numClasses, features,

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in first(self)
   1358         ValueError: RDD is empty
   1359         """
-> 1360         rs = self.take(1)
   1361         if rs:
   1362             return rs[0]

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1340 
   1341             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1342             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1343 
   1344             items += res

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
    966         # SparkContext#runJob.
    967         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
--> 968         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
    969         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
    970 

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 62.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 62.0 (TID 323, wlbimsprkprd01.opentext.net, executor 2): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 160, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 54, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 169, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 451, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1925)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1951)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 160, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 54, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 169, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 451, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The data is loaded through sql function and converted to RDD to use the mlib descision tree classifier function for RDDs but for some reason the function errors out on the classifier. Any comments or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full error stack?

Comment: @pedrambashiri : I  have put the full stack in the latest edit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is mentioned in the error stack trace.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

You just need to install numpy

```
pip install numpy
```

Generaly speaking, Spark does not do a great job in returning the actual cause of the exception to the driver. You need to go frthur down in the error stack trace to find it.